# List xml files in Flash builder Open Resource

Tags: flash, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

I use the Open Resource Window (Command-Shift-R) **a lot** in Flash Builder and it saves me a lot of time. But I can´t seem to get it to work with my projects xml files. I know this has been working on previous projects ut I can´t find any settings for this.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The Open resource window did not show "derived files". Problem solved.

[image]